# Running a test yii application gives object not found

Tags: yii

I have installed yii 1.1.12 framework(Windows 7 using xampp) and created a mytest project. I am able to see mytest project folder in the path '/xampp/htdocs/yii/framework/'. But while running application as 'http://localhost/mytest/' it gives Object not found error

Thanks,
Gowtham

Comment: yii1 or yii2? What steps have you followed?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's because you created your web app inside the framework folder, so the route localhost/mytest doesn't work. Try using http://localhost/yii/framework/mytest instead